# update prometheus charts from prometheus-operator to kube-prometheus-stack

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

Recently [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/b9278fa98cef543f5473eb55160eaf45833bc74e/stable/prometheus-operator) chart is deprecated and the chart has been renamed [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack#configuration) to more clearly reflect that it installs the kube-prometheus project stack, within which Prometheus Operator is only one component.

I checked both old and new chart and also I read all related documentation, but I couldn't find changes in the files(especially in `values.yaml`), could someone explain me to migrate from prometheus-operator to kube-prometheus-stack what I should do exactly?

Comment: We just started using Prometheus and saw the deprecation message, so installed kube-prometheus instead and customized the default values.yaml generated by helm show values prometheus-com/kube-prometheus-stack > custom-values.yaml. Is this not an option for you to move existing config into this? I believe you can also export existing dashboards/users and import or configure the new environment to use that. I know you have asked about migration/upgrade path, but wanted to share what I know.

Comment: @cnu yes at the moment I should just migrate the deprecated one to kube-prometheus, but the point is I checked all the components in values.yaml files in both prometheus-operator and kube-prometheus, and both are  the same, I just want to know what exactly change among them?

Answer (score 1):

**March 18, 2021**.

I migrated from *prometheus-operator* to *kube-prometheus-stack* and faced some difficulties.

Below is a list of errors which I encountered and the steps I took to work-around this.

---

**Error 1**: `unknown field "metricRelabelings"`.

**Solution**: Comment out all appearances.

---

**Error 2**: `unknown field "relabelings"`.

**Solution**: Comment out all appearances.

---

**Error 3**: `unknown field "selector" in com.coreos.monitoring.v1.Alertmanager.spec.storage.volumeClaimTemplate`.

**Solution**: Comment out all this specific field under the `volumeClaimTemplate`.

---

**Error 4**: `unknown field "shards" in com.coreos.monitoring.v1.Prometheus.spec`.

**Solution**: Comment out the specific location, or follow suggestions from [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/579).

---

**Error 5**: `prometheus-kube-stack unknown fields probenamespaceselector and probeSelector`.

**Solution**: As mentioned in [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/250#issuecomment-740813317), Delete all CRDs:

```
kubectl delete crd prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com
kubectl delete crd prometheusrules.monitoring.coreos.com
kubectl delete crd servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com
kubectl delete crd podmonitors.monitoring.coreos.com
kubectl delete crd alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com
kubectl delete crd thanosrulers.monitoring.coreos.com
```

And ran `helm install` again.

---

Link to the chart [issues page](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues) in Github.